# CATransformLayer: Autoresize sublayers to fill bounds?

Tags: cocoa, macos, core-animation, calayer, catransform3d

Is there any way to have the sublayers of a `CATransformLayer` automatically scale to fill the bounds of the `CATransformLayer` when animating? I've already tried setting the `autoresizingMask` property and also using `CAConstraintLayoutManager` but neither seem to have any effect.

The reason I want to do this is because I'm doing a 3D rotation + enlarge animation on the CATransformLayer, and the enlarge is not working because the sublayers aren't scaling to fill the bounds as it animates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually ended up just manually resizing the sublayers of the transform layer as it animated.